# how monitor root search path in linux RedHat 8.3?

Tags: linux, redhat

Due to security policies I have to regulary monitor root search PATH for any changes.
My question is what is best solution ?

Is enough to monitor just variable `$PATH`  or do I need to also monitor config files like:  /etc/profile, /bashrc ...?

Comment: What about LD_LIBRARY_PATH?   Do you plan to monitor that also?

Comment: Hi, Looks that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not part of my security audit requirement, so not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the procedure for security audit is to check the **current** status (when run the audit). So the simplest way is to run `echo $PATH` when login as (or become) root. This check will actually include "check" of `/etc/profile` and other related files

About how exactly to do the monitoring you can use ansible to collect info or monitoring program like nagios.